# Force use of online webfont instead of installed webfont

Tags: html, css, webfonts

The downloaded version of a font that I would like to use is different to the one that Google provides, and I was wondering if it was possible to force the user into using Google's version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this question's comment, if you use `@font-face` to embed your custom font onto your webpage, it will use your custom font not the one you installed on the computer.

My solution, while creating the custom font make sure to change its name and set it not equal to the one with which it's installed on the computer.

Hope I am clear and I solved your problem :)

Comment: It's not always possible to change the font-family name. I'm using Hoefler & Typekit webfonts which are embedded with a line of JS...so far the only way to force the font-face version is to disable the system font. Any solution for me?

Comment: Regarding Google fonts in question, do you mean to use neither link tag nor import, but to download them and upload them to your website? Any other possibility?

Comment: + beware, there are only ttf files in the download and the formats at the font's link are browser-specific. (https://css-tricks.com/dont-just-copy-the-font-face-out-of-google-fonts-urls/).. + is it legal to self-host googlefonts?

Answer (score 0):

You could use google webfont for that(http://www.google.com/fonts/).

When you click use,they show how to use the webfont: http://www.google.com/fonts/#UsePlace:use

Hoop this helps!

Comment: I'm using a Google webfont, but if the user has the same font installed on their pc it has slightly different formatting. What I want to do is to force them to use Google's version.

Comment: Can't you use a font family name that you know doesn't exist?

Comment: @MrLister that's what I recommended :)