# Forcing use of online webfont over local font, when unable to change font-family

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-family, typekit

I'm using a webfont that I also have installed on my system. I want the webpage to force the display of the remotely-served font INSTEAD of my local copy. [I've seen this question answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235934/force-use-of-online-webfont-instead-of-installed-webfont) except that solution assumes I can edit the font-family name, which I cannot (I'm using TypeKit and Hoefler fonts and they only provide a JS to load the fonts).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not [change the name of the font](http://www.fontgeek.net/blog/?cat=4) you have installed locally?

Comment: I'm looking for a browser/css-only solution. Also, any local file where I've specified those fonts will now bork when it can't find them.

Comment: If you can't edit the CSS/HTML, then what do you figure can accomplish in a browser? You'd have to edit the `@font-face` rule in the original CSS, or add/inject CSS that overrides the original `@font-face` with one that doesn't have the `local()` declaration in it.

Comment: We're on a Q&A site...I'm asking specifically because I *don't* know what I can or cannot do. For all I know there's some obscure font-family:arial[browser] command or something I can put in my CSS...who knows?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to overwrite the CSS generated by the Typekit JavaScript so that it skips the local version of the font. Examine the `@font-face` rule generated by Typekit, copy it to your CSS, and remove the `local()` part.

Comment: I've just had to amend the `@font-face` rule as per the above but there wasn't a `local` part - basically I just changed the font family name but kept the URLs the same